# Sudo unable to resolve host?

Tags: sudo, phpmyadmin, putty

I enter this command in PuTTY:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /var/www/phpmyadmin
```

But it returns:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host mysite.com
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked you host file ?

I mean If you haven't configured `localhost` properly at `/etc/hosts` then there chances of these errors.

To know more information about this : [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=799896)